# Can not display image - ANGULAR ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: html, angular, url, src

I'm working on Angular application and I can not display image on my website, 
I'm getting this messages in console:

```
unsafe:url(http://local.api.test.come/Uploads/af21cb1b-066c-48c6-b6d6-0116a133810d.jpg):1

GET unsafe:url(http://local.api.test.com/Uploads/af21cb1b-066c-48c6-b6d6-0116a133810d.jpg) net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

If I paste this path into browser I can easily preview image:

```
local.api.test.come/Uploads/af21cb1b-066c-48c6-b6d6-0116a133810d.jpg
```

But In my app it wont be loaded..

Here is my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let content of contents;">
  <div class="card-img-actions mx-1 mt-1">
    <img class="card-img img-fluid" [src]="'url('+ apiPath + content.path +')'" alt={{content.fileName}} />
  </div>
</div>
```

As It's possible to see `URL` is correct But I can not load image throught app..
if I enter `url` in browser as I said it opens image without any issues ...

P.S I've tried using sanitizer like this in my HTML(template):

```
[src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('url('+ apiPath + content.path +')')"
```

But than this appends `http://localhost:4200` + `full url` which is absolutly something that I dont want because resouce has nothing with `http://localhost:4200`

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Why are you using the `url()` attribute only available in CSS? You should be able to specify the URL directly in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you've mistaken the CSS [`url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()) function with the way to specify a URL/path for the [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src) attribute of an [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag. Instead, remove the surrounding `url()` portion in your code and replace it with the following:

```html
<div *ngFor="let content of contents">
  <div class="card-img-actions mx-1 mt-1">
    <img class="card-img img-fluid" [src]="apiPath + content.path" [alt]="content.fileName" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also please ensure api path has a scheme else it will be considered as a relative url

Comment: @Edric how come Url caused issues ?

Comment: Because you're supposed to just specify the URL without the `url()` appended to it. The `url()` part is meant for CSS. (I've already specified why it didn't work in my answer)